# Disable main screen in laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors, htpc

We have an old ASUS N61Jq laptop which we are now using as a HTPC.

I have changed the settings to:

- use monitor 2 (the TV) as the main display
- show desktop only on monitor 2
- do not sleep or anything when the lid is closed

The problem is whenever the lid is re-opened then display1 (the laptop screen) is re-enabled, and it goes back to "extend display over both monitors". This is annoying because it means you can lose the mouse (which is controlled by smart phone app) and that monitor 1 does not work with ATI display drivers due to [this bug](https://community.amd.com/thread/180511).

Is there any way to stop windows from re-activating monitor 1 when the lid is closed and openned?

Comment: Maybe Mirror Displays? (Hold the Windows key and hit P until you get to that option)

Comment: Doesn't Mirror Display mean I am restricted to the resolution of the smaller monitor?

Comment: Probably, yes :-/

Answer (score 0):

It may work to remove your laptop screen's display adaptor and/or monitor in [Device Manager](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000870.htm).